# The use of double vertical bars in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to find the reverse string program. There are many examples I have found but none explain what happens exactly inside the for loop:

```
DECLARE
ln_rev_input varchar2(50);
ln_input varchar2(50):= '&input';

BEGIN
     FOR i in reverse 1..length(ln_input) LOOP
         ln_rev_input := ln_rev_input||substr(ln_input, i, 1);
     END LOOP;
     dbms_output.put_line(ln_rev_input);
END;
```

I don't understand this line, especially the use of '||' in this program:

```
ln_rev_input := ln_rev_input||substr(ln_input, i, 1);
```

I know this '||' is used to concatenate strings but don't understand how exactly ln_rev_input is being assigned.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle/PLSQL `||` operator allows you to concatenate 2 or more strings together.

What the above code does is it is reversing an input string. Lets say you pass a string named `Oracle`, what it does is it starts from the end of the string `Oracle`, takes one character at a time using the function `substr(ln_input, i, 1)` and concatenates that character to whatever value is there in the `ln_rev_input` variable.

When it starts, `ln_rev_input` is null and the result of `ln_rev_input := ln_rev_input||substr(ln_input, i, 1);` will be `e`.

When it goes to the next iteration, the character `l` is concatenated to whatever value is there inside the variable `ln_rev_input`, that is `e` - so the piece of code is like

```
ln_rev_input := 'e' || 'l';
```

which will result in the value of `ln_rev_input` to be changed to `el`. This goes on for 6 times, which is the length of the string - which we found using `length(ln_input)` - and in the end, the value of `ln_rev_input` will be `elcarO`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. Thank you for the step-by-step response Saagar.